# Would a zombie-like virus affect animal populations or human populations more?

Tags: fauna, zombies

My story begins where a virus that can turn all living humans and animals on earth into a sort-of zombie-like decaying state, but also damages their brain, making them violent and unable to think rationally.

Recently, the virus has "escaped" from a lab. Since the virus can affect both humans (nearest ones to the virus live in a city about the size of Oakland CA) and animals (say a nearby ecosystem with bears, rabbits, and more), which would be more affected ("affected" meaning damage to population size and the size of the impact this will have on other things such as zombie bears attacking city humans))?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. It's a fictional virus in your fictional story, you decide the infection rate on each species.

Comment: How is the virus transmitted? Blood? Bodily Fluids? via Air? Does the person have to die first or will it kill the off? Can it also infect insects?

Comment: Since viruses can be transmitted in a variety of ways (see the @Shadowzee comment), and can be as virulent as you want it to be, and the *lab* can be wherever you want it to be, and have escaped however you want it to have escaped, the answer is completely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If the category "animals" includes insects being affected and serving as a vector we are all screwed pretty much immediately.

If the virus only affects mammals we're okay until it hits the rodent population.

Humans will fare better than animals initially but once the rodents turn we're totally screwed as will be everything else that can be infected by them.

Comment: Insects *are* in fact members of the biological kingdom *Animalia*.

Comment: @RonJohn well, to be honest, humans are also animals. sentient and evolved, but still animals

Comment: @Kepotx too true.  And viruses affect different species very differently.